# Retrieve Data from Access data base by vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I've enter data to the tables but I'm unable to retrieve data to text box in another form. I've listed the details that I've entered using student id. So I want to retrieve student_name according to student id...please help me...i tried to write select query but I failed...please tell me the code with select query..thank you

Comment: Dim cnn as new oledb.oledbconnection           Dim cmd as new oledb.oledbcommand.             cnn.connectionstring = "file path"                     cmd.connection = cnn           cmd.commandtext = "insert query"                           I came this far and data successfully saved.. And now I cant retrieve it from that tables

Comment: Why don't you guys help a student like me...pls help me..

Comment: What code do you wrote to retrieve data from DB ?